# iOS Address book import API: Any special handling needed for iCloud entries?

Tags: ios, addressbook

Please find below a code to import the iOS address book (lets assume we need to import - not just get a handle to it, for a specific need) --> some people using the app are complaining that only 15-20 of their addresses are being imported out of say 500. When one such person sent us their address book, I noticed besides 15-20 others are tagged as iCloud. This problem is not happening with everyone. Can someone tell us if we need to add special code for iCloud tagged entries? I don't think so, but confirming

```
- (void)getPersonOutOfAddressBook
{
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    isAddressBookAccessGranted=NO;

    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = nil;

      addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL)
    {
        //-- we're on iOS 6
        if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
        {
            ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                if (!granted)
                {
                    isAddressBookAccessGranted = NO;
                    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ERROR", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"ENABLE CONTACT ACCESS MESSAGE", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

                }
                else
                {
                    isAddressBookAccessGranted = YES;

                    [self loadAddressBook:addressBook];
                }
            });
        }
        else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        {
            isAddressBookAccessGranted = YES;

            {
                [self loadAddressBook:addressBook];
            }
        }
        else if(ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied)
        {
            isAddressBookAccessGranted = NO;
            UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ERROR", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"ENABLE CONTACT ACCESS MESSAGE", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
            // deleted some other code here - not related to addr book
        }
        else
        {
            //deleted some other code here - not related to addr book
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //-- we're on iOS 5 or older
        accessGranted = YES;
        isAddressBookAccessGranted = YES;
        [self loadAddressBook:addressBook];
    }
}

-(void) loadAddressBook:( ABAddressBookRef)currAddressBook
{
    if (currAddressBook != nil)
    {
        ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(currAddressBook);
        NSArray *allContacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(currAddressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
        NSUInteger i = 0;

       // if([AppDelegate sharedInstance].ABContactsArray!=nil)
            [mTempContactsArray removeAllObjects];

        for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
        {
            Person *person = [[[Person alloc] init] autorelease];

            ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];

            int recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(contactPerson);
            person.recordID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",recordID];
            NSLog(@"RecordID = %d\n", recordID);

            NSString *firstName = ( NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSLog(@"firstName = %@\n", firstName);

            NSString *lastName =  ( NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
            NSLog(@"lastName = %@\n", lastName);

            NSString *fullName;

            if(!(firstName==nil) && !(lastName==nil))
                fullName= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
            else if((firstName==nil) && (lastName==nil))
                fullName = @"";//[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"NO NAME STORED", nil)];
            else if (firstName==nil)
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lastName];
            else if(lastName==nil)
                fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstName];

            person.firstName = firstName;
            person.lastName = lastName;
            person.fullName = fullName;

            person.imageData = ( NSData *) ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contactPerson, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

            NSLog(@"imageData = %@\n", person.imageData);

            ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
            NSUInteger count=0;
            NSUInteger j = 0;
            person.numberDetailArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] autorelease] ;
            for (j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
            {
                NSString *contactCategory;
                NSString *phone = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);
                NSLog(@"phone number = %@\n", phone);

                NSString *phoneLabel = (__bridge NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j);
                NSLog(@"phoneLabel = %@\n", phoneLabel);


                if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
                {
                    contactCategory = @"mobile";
                    count++;
                }
                else if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
                {
                    contactCategory = @"iPhone";
                    count++;
                }
                else if([phoneLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMainLabel])
                {
                    contactCategory = @"main";
                    count++;
                }
                else if ([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
                {
                    contactCategory = @"home";
                    count++;
                }
                else if ([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
                {
                    contactCategory = @"work";
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    contactCategory = @"other";
                    count++;
                }

                NumberInfo *numberInfo = [[[NumberInfo alloc]init] autorelease];
                numberInfo.contactNumberCategory = contactCategory;
                numberInfo.contactNumber = phone;

                numberInfo.parentID = person.recordID;

                //numberInfo.recordType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kNumberRecord];
                [person.numberDetailArray addObject:numberInfo];
                if(phone)
                    CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(phone));
                if(phoneLabel)
                    CFRelease((__bridge CFStringRef)(phoneLabel));
            }

            person.phoneNumberCount= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)count];

            [mTempContactsArray addObject:person];
            if(phones)
                CFRelease(phones);
                    }
        if(source)
            CFRelease(source);

        NSLog(@"count=%d",[mTempContactsArray count]) ;
    }

    //-- after loading all the contacts, perform the table view operations on main thread
   // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initializeSharedContactList) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over all address book sources, not just the default one. Use `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources` to get all sources, then iterate all sources and get contacts using `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering`.

Comment: Leo thank you. We just tested this change with our clients who were having issues and this nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating through sources, you can just use ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople to pull everyone.

As a side note, when you do this you may get what appear to be duplicate entries.  Contacts consolidates these into a unified contact page, but if you have Bob Smith synced from Facebook and iCloud, you'll have two ABRecords for Bob Smith - one from each source.

Comment: thanks. I did not try this solution given that Leo's one worked, but good to know.